# How to solve the following ODE with a parameter?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, singularity-theory

I am considering the following ODE
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\frac{d^2}{dy^2}u + \frac{\alpha}{(1+y^2)^{\frac{r}{2}}}u = \delta(y)\\
&\lim_{|y|\to \infty}u(y) = 0.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Here $\alpha$ is a constant and $r > 0$ and $\delta(y)$ is the Dirac delta function. Is it possible to solve this ODE? I expect the solution to be singular in $\alpha$ as $\alpha$ approaches zero. If we can't get the explicit expression of the solution, can we analyze its singularity in $\alpha$ asymptotically as $\alpha \to 0$? For example, when $r = 0$, the solution behaves like $\frac{e^{-|y|\sqrt{-\alpha}}}{\sqrt{-\alpha}}$ which is singular in $\alpha$.

Comment: What is $\delta$?

Comment: Dirac delta function?

Comment: Yes, $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.

Comment: (i) Does $\alpha$ have a definite sign? (ii) Why do you call $u$ the fundamental solution and why is it of interest? -- The ODE is not with constant coefficients, and so, the general solution of the ODE is probably not the convolution of the right-hand side with your $u$.

Comment: In principle, $\alpha$ can be complex numbers since we only care about the case when $\alpha$ is near zero. I agree that now the fundamental solution is not a convolution kernel. But I think we still can define a fundamental solution (or Green's function) for this linear ODE. Do you mean the fundamental solution for this ODE is not defined by setting right-hand side $\delta$?

Comment: I think, if you know all the solutions with $\delta(y-y_0)$ on the right-hand side for all real $y_0$, then in a sense you know all the solutions. But only knowing the solutions with $\delta(y)$ on the right-hand side is not enough.

Comment: Oh yes, that's a good point. I think in both cases the singularity in $\alpha$ should be similar.

Comment: "For example, when $r = 0$, the solution behaves like $\frac{e^{-|y|\sqrt{-\alpha}}}{\sqrt{-\alpha}}$ which is singular in $\alpha$." -- (i) What do you mean by **the** solution? (The general solution depends on two constants.) (ii) How do you get such a statement? If $\alpha=0$, then a solution is given by $u(y)=\max(0,y)$. How do you get the singularity at all?

Comment: I should emphasize that the solution $u(y)$ goes to zero as $|y|$ goes to infinity. If we set $\alpha$ to be zero, the solution is explicitly solvable and there seems to be no singularity in $\alpha$. However, the solution is not continuous with respect to $\alpha$ as $\alpha$ goes to 0. In fact, when $\alpha$ is small but not equal to 0, the solution should exhibit singularity in $\alpha$.

Comment: "For example, when $r = 0$, the solution behaves like $\frac{e^{-|y|\sqrt{-\alpha}}}{\sqrt{-\alpha}}$ which is singular in $\alpha$." Again, how do you get this? I think, when $r=0$ and $\alpha>0$, any solution is periodic.

Comment: For $r = 0$, the solution should be like $Ae^{\sqrt{-\alpha}y} + Be^{-\sqrt{-\alpha}y}$. Note the right-hand side is a Dirac delta and the condtion $u(\infty) = 0$. The solution should be like $Ae^{-|y|\sqrt{-\alpha}}$. Of course one should be careful with the sign of $\alpha$ here. $A$ is like $1/\sqrt{-\alpha}$ because the constant before $\delta$ is 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is essentially an elliptic second-order ODE in $(0,\infty)$:
$$ (1 + y^2)^{r/2} u''(y) = (-\alpha) u(y) , $$
with boundary conditions $u'(0) = -1$ and $u(\infty) = 0$. This kind of problems are well-studied, the corresponding theory is known as *Krein's spectral theory of strings*.

The value $h(\alpha)$ of $u$ at $0$ for the given parameter $\alpha$ is the corresponding *spectral function*, and $h(-\alpha)$ is a Stieltjes function of $\alpha$ (other names: Nevanlinna–Pick function, Herglotz function). The relation between the coefficient (here: $(1+y^2)^{-r/2}$, roughly known as the *string*) and the spectral function $h$ is not explicit, but some comparison results are known.

I do not have time now to search for the relevant results, but I would start by looking at the following paper:

- S. Kotani and S. Watanabe, *Krein's spectral theory of strings and generalized diffusion processes*, in: Functional Analysis in Markov processes (Katata/Kyoto, 1981), Lecture Notes in Math. 923, Springer, Berlin, 1982, 235–259, [DOI:10.1007/BFb0093046](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0093046).

Another excellent reference with a chapter on Krein's theory is

- R. Schilling, R. Song, Z. Vondraček, *Bernstein Functions: Theory and Applications*. De Gruyter, Studies in Math. 37, Berlin, 2012, [DOI:10.1515/9783110269338](https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110269338).

---

*Edit: some additional details.*

Strictly speaking, our case corresponds to the *string* $m(dy) = (1 + y^2)^{-r/2} dy$, which is commonly identified with its distribution function $$m(y) = m([0, y)) = \int_0^y (1 + s^2)^{-r/2} ds.$$

The spectral function can be defined in a number of equivalent ways: one of them inolves the integral of $(\phi_N)^{-2}$, where $\phi_N$ is the solution with "Neumann" initial condition $\phi_N(0) = 1$, $\phi_N'(0) = 0$. The one I am most familiar with defines it to be the reciprocal of $-\phi'(0)$, where $\phi$ is the solution with boundary conditions $\phi(0) = 1$ and $\phi(\infty) = 0$. This is clearly equivalent to the definition as $-u'(0)$ with $u$ as in the statement of the problem.

I failed once to find a simple reference for the above calculation in analytical terms, so together with Jacek Mucha we included a very brief discussion in the appendix to our paper (see Section A.3 therein):

- J. Mucha, M. Kwaśnicki, *Extension technique for complete Bernstein functions of the Laplace operator*, J. Evol. Equ. 18(3) (2018): 1341–1379 [DOI:10.1007/s00028-018-0444-4](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00028-018-0444-4).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It's very helpful. I read the first reference you mentioned and got two questions. It seems for the ODE in my problem, the string should be defined as $\int_0^y\frac{1}{(1+z^2)^{r/2}}dz$? I found the Krein spectral function is defined as an integral in that reference. Why is the value $u(0)$ called the spectral function in our situation?

Comment: I added some details that hopefully address your questions.

Comment: Thanks! That answers my questions. Do you think it is possible to get the asymptotic behaviour of $u(y, \alpha)$ as $|y| \to \infty$? I guess the solution would behave like $h(\alpha)e^{-\frac{1}{h(\alpha)}|y|}$ if we pretend the behaviour is similar to the case $r = 0$.

Comment: When $y$ is large, the behaviour of $u(\alpha, y)$ should be quite different! I expect something like $c_1(\alpha) \exp(-c_2(\alpha) |y|^{1-r/2})$ — at least this is what one gets for the explicitly solvable coefficient $(1+|y|)^{-r}$ instead of $(1+y^2)^{-r/2}$. (I may have made a mistake, though.)

Comment: This is interesting! The index $1-r/2$ in the exponential looks very reasonable. I guess the two coefficients $(1+y^2)^{-r/2}$ and $(1+|y|)^{-r}$ would give solutions with similar asymptotic behavior. But I don't know how to get the explicit solution for the $(1+|y|)^{-r}$ case. I also failed to check the function you give is a solution. Do you know if there is any reference on this case? Thanks!

Comment: The coefficient $y^{-r}$ (where $y > 0$) is the one appearing in the Caffarelli–Silvestre extension technique, the solution is given by the Bessel $K$ function; see, for example, Section 5.2 in my paper with Jacek Mucha. Getting from here to $(1+y)^{-r}$ is easy: just consider $-u(1+y)/u'(1)$. And $(1+|y|)^{-r}$ corresponds to $u(|y|)$.